# Magento: 1.9.X - Improvement on Upgrade Sales Orders Grid

Tags: magento-1.9

It seems that magento function `updateGridRecords` update all entries from sales_flat_order_grid. All good, but if we have more than 100k orders, that function failed to update/insert all the entries. There is a method in order to remove existing order ids from the select and update only new orders?

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do this but I choosed the following because the project already have some functions overridden, so:

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
        <sales_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <order>Namespace_Module_Model_Rewrite_Mage_Sales_Resource_Order</order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales_resource>
    </models>
</config>
```

On the following path we will put the new query that select only the new orders ids:

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Rewrite/Mage/Sales/Resource/Order.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Rewrite_Mage_Sales_Resource_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order
{
    public function getUpdateGridRecordsSelect($ids, &$flatColumnsToSelect, $gridColumns = null)
    {
        // ###### BEGIN customization, reset orders ids ######
        $ids = [];
        $firstTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order');
        $secondTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_grid');
        $newOrders = $this->_getReadAdapter()
            ->select()
            ->from(['main_table' => $firstTable], ['entity_id'])
            ->joinLeft(['grid' => $secondTable], 'main_table.entity_id = grid.entity_id', [])
            ->where('grid.entity_id IS NULL')
        ;
        if (!empty($newOrders)) {
            $ids = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol($newOrders);
        }
        // ###### END customization ######

        $flatColumns = array_keys($this->_getReadAdapter()
            ->describeTable(
                $this->getMainTable()
            )
        );
        if ($gridColumns === null) {
            $gridColumns = $this->getGridColumns();
        }
        $flatColumnsToSelect = array_intersect($flatColumns, $gridColumns);
        $select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), $flatColumnsToSelect)
            ->where('main_table.' . $this->getIdFieldName() . ' IN(?)', $ids);

        $this->joinVirtualGridColumnsToSelect('main_table', $select, $flatColumnsToSelect);
        return $select;
    }
```

A better way to do this is through `sales_resource_update_grid_records` event, where you will have all the orders ids and can perform same query on the object.